# InfoPath timeout is too short

Tags: infopath

We have a web service that returns a fairly large amount of data that InfoPath consumes.  The service takes a little while to run (say 10 seconds) which is too long for InfoPath, it times out around 5 seconds.

Is there some way of increasing the timeout for this form?

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer here --> http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/1615/1615.aspx
it says i can increase the timeout in the script.js in my infopath solution.